# Create a Solana Pay Transaction Request: when scanning QR code phantom wallet exits app

Tags: transactions, solana-pay

I am building a eCommerce site demo with Solana Pay as the payment method. Now, I am trying to setup the transaction request with a GET and POST endpoint deployed on AWS Lambda under the serverless framework. However, I am not sure why when I use my phantom wallet or FTX app to scan (I have USDC and sol in the wallets), it directly exits the app back to the home screen.

I made sure to conform to all the Solana specificitions (content encoding enabled on AWS API Gateway console). The endpoint is "solana:[https://62qhh5s68b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/pay-usdc"](https://62qhh5s68b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/pay-usdc%22)

Do you possibly know what could the issue be? (The get and post code are from this: https://docs.solanapay.com/core/transaction-request/merchant-integration, except that I use the serverless framework and deployed on lambda)
[image: POST]
[image: GET]

```
    const index = async (request, context, callback) => {
  // We set up our handler to only respond to `GET` and `POST` requests.
  let response = null;
  
  if (request.account?.length !== undefined && request.account?.length > 0) {
    response = await handlePayment(request);
  }
  else {
    response = await getPaymentInfo(request); 
  }  

  try {
    callback(null, response);
  } catch (e) {
    callback(e);
  }

};
```

Comment: What cluster are you connected to? Devnet?

Comment: I connected to "mainnet-beta"

Comment: Hmm are you able to check your server logs to see if it reports any errors?

Comment: Can you show the QR code you're using too?

Comment: @C_Ogoo It wasn't until a few minutes ago. Previously, it was only responding with the GET response and not able to distinguish incoming request method as GET or POST, so I directly added check for req.account, which, weirdly, works now. So yes, the server log came back with the right response now -- with each phantom wallet scans, there is a GET first, and then a POST request, both came back the right response. But phantom still exits me to the home screen...

Comment: QR code: https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=solana:https://62qhh5s68b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/pay-usdc @CallumM

Comment: Server logs: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1po7HX7dfg9xB3vTKAErQpQ37QYVLrsIk?usp=sharing

Comment: It's impossible to know for sure without Phantom source, but the issue might be that you're not URL encoding the QR code. It should be eg. `solana:https%3A%2F%2F62qhh5s68b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com%2Fdev%2Fpay-usdc` But when I tried putting that into the api.qrserver.com that you're using they decoded it in the created QR. So if that is the issue then you won't be able to use that QR generator because it needs to be URL encoded after the `solana`

Comment: Though if I put that URL into https://www.qr-code-generator.com then Phantom still crashes. But I don't know if there's anything different in your logs?

Comment: There isn't anything different in the logs if I used the encoded URL and qr-code-generator.com. One thing I noticed is that when you scan at around 10:18 am ET, it says "customer wallet not found". Are you using a specialty wallet? @CallumM

Comment: I was using Phantom, but it was a dev account with no mainnet activity so depending what you're doing in your API that might be the cause?

Comment: @CallumM Got it. I am strictly using 'mainnet-beta' both in the api and with my wallet. I've already encoded the url like you mentioned and used qr-code-generator. Are there any other issues that could have caused the wallet exits? If you look at the server logs / responses, both returns the right responses. (uploaded my code here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1po7HX7dfg9xB3vTKAErQpQ37QYVLrsIk?usp=sharing)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you try this with the solflare wallet?

Comment: @C.OG worked with Solfare! Weirdly doesn't work with phantom